# Do some Red Sphere, Blue Sphere stages have more blue spheres than required?

Tags: sonic-mania

IIRC, the Red Sphere, Blue Sphere stages in S3&K all required you to collect every one of the blue spheres on the stage. But I could swear I've had a few instances in *Sonic Mania* where I've finished a stage with blue spheres left in front of me. Do some of the later stages have surplus blue spheres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely finish a blue sphere stage with some number of spheres still remaining. I'm *pretty sure* this is a bug, but I haven't found any definitive sources. I have seen people mentioning this on Twitter before.

I did find [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/speedrun/comments/6y43tl/new_sonic_mania_glitch_lets_you_skip_blue_spheres/) where user [Domilego4](https://www.reddit.com/user/Domilego4) offers a theory:

> I'm guessing the way the game removes one additional blue sphere from
>   the counter when you clear a 3x3 square is that it checks for three
>   things:
>
> - If the four corners have turned red
> - If Sonic is within the 3x3 square
> - If rings have been spawned at that location
>
> Now, if you watch the video again, you can see that those three
>   conditions are true, so the game removed another blue sphere from the
>   counter.

Comment: So you're saying that, rather than there being surplus spheres, the game is subtracting too many spheres in some cases when you clear a square?

Comment: Yeah, this is the same stage in which I've seen it: https://www.reddit.com/r/speedrun/comments/6y43tl/comment/dmmstsf

Comment: @rensa I've seen both cases: finishing a stage with spheres remaining on the count, and the count reaching zero even though there are spheres still in the world. The stage is considered completed in either case.